Combining a differential amp and current limiting circuit
I've been experimenting with a very simple current limiter that regulates the current through a solenoid with a 3-4 ohm resistance.

The external driving circuit is a PWM switched N-Ch MOSFET providing a current path to ground. There is a burst of about 40ms full power, and then a PWM signal switching really slowly in the range of a few kHz to provide holding power. The +48V is approximate at best as it comes from a supply without the best output impedance. I have no control over that. My widget has to play the cards it has been dealt.
This little circuit works-ish (if I parallel and heatsink a couple of MOSFETs). The goal is to have a solenoid that fires with constant power (at least more predictable) if the coil warms up a bit or if the supply sags a little. Balancing the coil load impedance and power dissipation in the semiconductors to a happy equilibrium.
It's not great having to use the vbe of the pnp to set the threshold as

It's hard to trim the circuit
The vbe is different between devices and temperature dependent itself.

I was thinking a differential amplifier might be a nice addition here to give a much more stable current reading across the shunt. I made a simple one in isolation and have a cursory understanding of the upgrades like a current mirror and constant current sources to improve stability that I can experiment with later.
What I can't figure out is how to combine the 2 circuits and bias it all correctly so I can use a very low resistance shunt (guessing I can use some negative feedback like in an opamp circuit to control gain and make the current to the load trim-able). Can someone push me in the right direction by merging the schematics? Either that or tell my why this is an awful way to go about this challenge. I could try a dedicated current sense amplifier but the +48v seems over the supply voltage range of the devices I have looked at
The image below is from an answer (by Russell McMahon and copied here under license CC BY-SA 4.0) to one of my questions "Help needed optimising simple current limiting circuit" a long time ago just for reference (but unfortunately the links in that old answer are dead for the original reference to the image).


@russell-mcmahon thought I'd tag you here in the comments to see if you have any input now I'm back with a similar challenge 12 years later

Ah just ordered some MAX4080s https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max4080-max4081.pdf
